# creating new excel rows when the column reaches a specific number

Tags: java, filewriter

I have the below code which is getting data from a text area and put it in an excel sheet.

my problem is that, it doesn't move to next row when column reaches 8.

if my text area contains as below:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

the result is shown in excel as below picture , and last column contains 2 numbers !!

[image]

I need it to look as :

[image]

what am I doing wrong ?

my code:

```
        try {
                    //create .xls and create a worksheet.
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("My Work Sheet");
                    Desktop desktop2 = Desktop.getDesktop();

                    //Create ROW-1 ((row line number in the excel))
                    HSSFRow row1 = null;
                    //Create COL-A from ROW-1 and set data
                    HSSFCell cellA1 = null;

                    String[] strings = getTextArea_1.split("\t");
                    //String[] rows = getTextArea_1.split("\n");             
                    int rowLines = 0;
                    //row1 = worksheet.createRow(rowLines);
                    int colLine = 0;
                    row1 = worksheet.createRow(rowLines);

                    for(String b : strings) {
                        while(colLine <= 8) {
                            cellA1 = row1.createCell(colLine);
                            cellA1.setCellValue(b);
                            break;
                        }
                        colLine++;
                        rowLines++;
                    }

                    //Save the workbook in .xls file
                    workbook.write(fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();

                    // to open the text file
                    if(excelFile.exists()) {
                        if(!getTextArea_1.isEmpty()) {
                            desktop2.open(excelFile);
                        }
                        else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea_1, "Please search your data first", "NO DATA TO EXTRACT", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
});
```